# Wireless Networking Issue

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, laptop

So I own two laptops. I have a basic Comcast Gateway/Wireless Router and also a Linksys E1200 Wireless N Router.

I have been struggling with one of my laptops not connecting at full speeds on any network. I get upwards of 50mbps on my Toshiba laptop and only about 10-20 on my HP Laptop.

I dont think the specs matter on them. They are both running Windows 7 Ultimate Sp1. The Toshiba has an Intel Centrino Wireless N 2230 Card, and the HP has an Intel Dual Band Wireless AC 7260 card. I have swapped these cards around, and they both perform at full speed on the Toshiba, but not the HP.

The thing that is strange is that if I have the Linksys router set to Wireless N Mode Only, the HP cannot connect. Windows says it cant connect and never Associates according to the troubleshooter. As soon as I change the settings on the Linksys to Mixed Mode it connects and has speeds between 10-20mbps. This same thing happens with the Intel Centrino Wireless N 2230 card installed. So I am completely stumped... It cant be my antennas, it cant be the card, since they both work perfectly fine in my Toshiba, and I dont see how it could be motherboard related since the card does function. Anyone have any ideas? I have the same, updated drivers on both machines for both cards.

Comment: Paragraphs help readability.

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling PPPoE or/and PPP in your router settings.You can get there by typing in ipconfig (on windows) and type in your gateway address into your browser.
Good Luck.